# Create shadow like this in android side drawer

Tags: android

[image]

How to create like this shadow in android side drawer? 
Please help.

Comment: [ShapeDrawable with gradient](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

Answer (score 1):

I am adding new layout as above how to add

Answer (score 0):

**1. Create a custom drawable for shadow e.g shadow_right.xml**

shadow_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp">

        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
            <!-- change angle value below and see the effect-->
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:centerColor="#14000000"
                android:endColor="#44000000"
                android:gradientRadius="2" />

        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

**2. Add drawable i.e. shadow_right as a background**

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <View
              android:id="@+id/viewRight"
              android:layout_width="10dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"                
              android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
              android:background="@drawable/shadow_right"
              android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**3. Replace the color values in shadow_right.xml**

Comment: thanks, but i am littlebit confuse,, i adding my layout below,, please tell me where we add this code..

Comment: <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout><android.support.design.widget.NavigationView >
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:scrollbars="none">
            </RelativeLayout>
              </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>